# Eclipse ADT export apk falied

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am using ADT (build v22.6.2-1085508) and eclipse to create my android applications. When I am trying to export signed application I am getting the following error message from the wxport wizard `Failed to export application` and nothing else.

Have anyone met this problem before?

Comment: just clean your project and retry it

Comment: Its very buggy! Refresh, Clean your project. If it still doesnt work, restart Eclipse. If it still doesnt work then restart your system! Something or the other should work

Comment: Update your ADT = v23.0.2 is recent, v22 is not.

Answer (score 1):

I did clean my project and rebuild it. The issue was that I had some directories named with Greek characters though.